# Given measure zero $X \subset [0,1]^2$, find dense $Y \subset [0,1]^2$ s.t. no absolute differences of pairs are in $X$

Tags: real-analysis

Given measure zero $X \subset [0,1]^2$, is there a dense subset $Y \subset [0,1]^2$ such that for all distinct pairs $y,y' \in Y$, we have $(|y_1 - y'_1|,|y_2 - y'_2|) \notin X$ ?

This generalizes a question which asks to find dense $Y \subset [0,1]^2$ such that no two points in $Y$ lie on a common horizontal or vertical line. In that case, $X = \{(0,a) : a \in [0,1]\} \cup \{(a,0) : a \in [0,1]\}$, which has measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised, since I had misread the question.**

Let $X^+=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in[-1,1]^2:\langle |x|,|y|\rangle\in X\}\cup\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$; clearly $m(X^+)=0$. For $p\in[0,1]^2$ let $X_p=(p+X^+)\cap[0,1]^2$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable base for the topology of $[0,1]^2$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$ choose a point

$$p_n\in B_n\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}X_{p_k}\;;$$

this is always possible, since $m(B_n)>0=m\left(\bigcup_{k<n}X_{p_k}\right)$. Then $Y=\{p_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a dense subset of $[0,1]^2$, and $p_m-p_n\notin X^+$ whenever $m,n\in\Bbb N$ with $m\ne n$, which is a restatement of the desired condition.

Comment: I believe this is correct to construct dense $Y$ disjoint from $X$, but my question is asking for something different.

Comment: @user2566092: You’re right. However, the same basic idea works to get what you want, now that I’ve managed to read the question correctly; I’ve revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of the same modification this morning but you beat me to it. :) I like this result because for example it says you can find dense $Y$ such that no two points in $Y$ lie on any line with a slope in an uncountable measure zero set of slopes. Way beyond the case of finding dense $Y$ so that no two points lie on a common horizontal or vertical line (just 2 slopes to avoid).

Comment: @user2566092: You’re welcome. It’s a nice teaching example, too: it shows that sometimes you don’t have to work much harder to get a lot more.